# Add a 2d library on Android studio ( withwith preexisting layout files )

Tags: android, android-studio, libgdx, andengine, 2d-games

I was programming a menu with different buttons. Know, if i click on 1 button ( mental arithmetic for example ), I should be open a 2D basic game.
I searched libraries that could help me and I found LibGDX and AndEngine.
But there is a problem : I cannot Add LibGDX to my Project there is gradle's build problem. And the same with AndEngine.

How can I add a 2D game ( write in java ) to my initial project ? Knowing there is problems with the importing project ( on Android Studio ) 
Thanks

Edit : I follow the tutorial and now there is my problem : I don't know how I can add my Layout files to the project. I want to start the Android Emulator with my xml file ( with the 5 buttons ) and currently my project start with libGDX ( with badlogic's picture and a red screen )

Second Edit : I finally solve my problem : I change a Line in my manifest.xml and I didn't know there was a line who start the application

Answer (score 1):

You should fix the build problem that you have then try to import a project, i think you could achieve what you want to do with Libgdx library, try to follow step by step this tutorial : How to setup Libgdx for Android Studio

http://www.programmingmoney.com/setup-libgdx-android-studio/

and if you have a problem posted so we could help you to fix it

Good luck !

Comment: Thank you,  I will try your tutorial and I will post in order to inform about my build project.

Comment: Ok i read the tutorial, and when we have to import project, there is two options : "import project" or " import project (eclipse ADT,Gradle ). I choose the second option because we want the gradle file. And after that I choose the AndroidStudioProjects/GDXThirdTest/build.gradle file.  So I choose the file, and I have a read access problem :

Comment: There is the probleme in event log :  Read access is allowed from event dispatch thread or inside read-action only (see com.intellij.openapi.application.Application.runReadAction())
         Details: Current thread: Thread[Thread-1,5,main] 117334302
         ; dispatch thread: false; isDispatchThread(): false
         SystemEventQueueThread: Thread[AWT-EventQueue-1 1.5#AI-141.2456560